# Typescript/Jest doesn't recognize Web Workers

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, web-worker

I'm trying to use Web Workers with Typescript. I have a project with the following structure:

```
__tests__
|
| test.ts
--- 
src
|
| something.ts
| someelse.ts
--- 
jest.config.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{ 
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["webworker", "es2015", "scripthost"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.1.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "webpack": "^4.41.4",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.2.0"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
}
```

The IDE recognizes the `Worker` class just fine, but I can't run any Jest test. I get an error when the program tries to instantiate a member of the Worker class:

```
$> npm test

> test-ts@1.0.0 test $
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/tests.ts
  × basic (3ms)

  ● basic

    ReferenceError: Worker is not defined

       9 |   receiveUpdate(id: string, shipmentData: any) {
      10 |     if (!this.idToWorker[id]) {
    > 11 |       const worker = new Worker('worker.ts');
         |                      ^
      12 |       this.idToWorker[id] = { worker, processed: [] };
      13 |       const _idToWorker = this.idToWorker[id];
      14 |       this.idToWorker[id].worker.addEventListener("message", message => {

      at ShipmentUpdateListener.receiveUpdate (src/listener.ts:11:22)
      at Object.<anonymous>.test (__tests__/tests.ts:5:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.99s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What's the problem? Is there a way to have Jest transpile TS to JavaScript so that it recognizes the Worker class?

Thanks.

Comment: any updates on this?